# Fix flutter printing pacakge UI

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, printing

I am trying to print a PDF from flutter. I pubget the printing package via pub.dev.

https://pub.dev/packages/printing

[image]

After running the app following the example, press the printer icon button to move the screen.

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to fix the Save as PDF part shown above. I couldn't find the UI part even if I searched along the class.

I noticed that the view is switched through the _print method of the PdfPreview class, but after that, I couldn't find where to make the UI and make it work.

Do you know a dart file or class that makes UI?

***main.dart***

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp('Printing Demo'));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp(this.title, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  PdfDocument? _doc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
        body: PdfPreview(
          build: (format) => _generatePdf(format, title),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format, String title) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document(version: PdfVersion.pdf_1_5, compress: true);
    final font = await PdfGoogleFonts.nunitoExtraLight();

    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: format,
        build: (context) {
          return pw.Column(
            children: [
              pw.SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: pw.FittedBox(
                  child: pw.Text(title, style: pw.TextStyle(font: font)),
                ),
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
              pw.Flexible(child: pw.FlutterLogo())
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    return pdf.save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this somehow ? I'm facing the same issue and it is cutting off my text from the pdf

Answer (score 1):

You cant change printing view - is handled by system. I belive this is how this package works - it sends data to another Intenet

Comment: In order to print without using the package of pub.dev, is the only way to implement it through dart?

Comment: Nope. it wont be trival. You need to check what API uses  Printing service and try to rewrite it with dart.